# Running sqoop using python subprocess can't recognize the arguments

Tags: python, subprocess, sqoop

When I run *sqoop export* from terminal it runs properly.But executing it from python scripts returns error:

```
*ERROR tool.BaseSqoopTool: Unrecognized argument: --connect
ERROR tool.BaseSqoopTool: Unrecognized argument: --table
ERROR tool.BaseSqoopTool: Unrecognized argument: --export_dir*
```

Following is the code snippet:

```
call(["/usr/local/sqoop/bin/sqoop","export","--connect jdbc:mysql://localhost/temp","--table table1" ,"--export-dir /user/data/input" ,"--username root"])
```

Assuming imported the subprocess module

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The single arguments in your argument list shouldn't contain any whitespaces. The line should look like this:

```
call(["/usr/local/sqoop/bin/sqoop","export","--connect", "jdbc:mysql://localhost/temp","--table", "table1" ,"--export-dir", "/user/data/input" ,"--username", "root"])
```